# In Javascript, how to transform an Object into a Number and Back Again?

Tags: javascript, hash

On my webpage I have a status object that stores a few values.

```
var status = { animal: "cat", page: 4};
```

I would like to be able to update the URL with a unique ID that represents that state of the status object.

```
http://my.website#/searchPage/472940283648
```

The javascript on the page would need to read in the number, and from it produce a status object.

I suppose I could save the status object in a database, but is there a way to convert the object into a reversable hash of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) function to encode a string with base64 scheme. And [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) to decode it back.

```
var obj = { animal: "cat", page: 4 };

// Encode to base64
var hash = btoa(JSON.stringify(obj));

// Decode back to object
var decodedObj = JSON.parse(atob(hash));
```

If you want to put it in URL, don't forget to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) first, since base64 may contain a character like: `=`, `+`, `/`.

```
var hashPart = encodeURIComponent(btoa(JSON.stringify(obj)));
var url = 'http://my.website#/searchPage/' + hashPart;

// Decode the uri first
var decodedObj = JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(hashPart)));
```

Also, note that the [`status` variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status) is part of the global variables on some browsers.